# How can I remove the box-shadow after clicking away from the input box?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var fname = "";
var lname = "";
var email = "";
var password = "";
var repassword= "";

$("#fn").keyup(function(){

var vall = $(this).val();

if(vall == "") {
    $("#fnerror").html("Please enter your first name");
    $(".f_n").css({"border-color": "#da0707", "box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 1px #dab6b6, 0 0 8px #da0707", "margin-bottom": "0"});
    $("#fnerror").removeClass("valid-container").addClass("error-container");
    fname = "";
}
else if(vall.length < 3) {
    $("#fnerror").html("First name is too short");
    $(".f_n").css({"border-color": "#da0707", "box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 1px #dab6b6, 0 0 8px #da0707", "margin-bottom": "0"});
    $("#fnerror").removeClass("valid-container").addClass("error-container");
    fname = "";
}
else {
    $("#fnerror").html("Awesome!");
    $(".f_n:focus").css({"border-color": "#5cb85c", "margin-bottom": "0", "box-shadow": "rgb(37, 187, 10) 0px 1px 1px inset, rgb(22, 134, 14) 0px 0px 8px"});
    $("#fnerror").removeClass("error-container").addClass("valid-container");

    fname = vall;
}

});

});
```

I wish to only have a box-shadow when the `input` has :focus, other than that I want the border-color and margin-bottom remain the same like in the script.

**EDIT: This is my form validation unfortunately.

Comment: No JS required - apply those CSS rules on the element using the `:focus` pseudo selector

Comment: Why not pure CSS `input {  }` and [`input:focus {   }`??](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/)

Comment: u can achieve it using css, why this much of javascript?

Comment: Let me explain the situation. The script above changes the border-color and box-shadow upon errors. So normal CSS :focus doesn't apply well because it won't react to the errors being output.

Comment: i suggest remove the css declaration on js, declare a css class for each state and toggle each class depending on state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't use CSS because of dynamic updates, and most likely `#fn` and `.f_n` aren't the same element *(otherwise you should `this`)*, you can just remove the box-shadow on blur

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var fname = "";
    var lname = "";
    var email = "";
    var password = "";
    var repassword = "";

    $("#fn").on({
        keyup : function() {
            var vall = $(this).val();

            if (vall == "") {
                $("#fnerror").html("Please enter your first name");
                $(".f_n").css({
                    "border-color": "#da0707",
                    "box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 1px #dab6b6, 0 0 8px #da0707",
                    "margin-bottom": "0"
                });
                $("#fnerror").removeClass("valid-container").addClass("error-container");
                fname = "";
            } else if (vall.length < 3) {
                $("#fnerror").html("First name is too short");
                $(".f_n").css({
                    "border-color": "#da0707",
                    "box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 1px #dab6b6, 0 0 8px #da0707",
                    "margin-bottom": "0"
                });
                $("#fnerror").removeClass("valid-container").addClass("error-container");
                fname = "";
            } else {
                $("#fnerror").html("Awesome!");
                $(".f_n").css({
                    "border-color": "#5cb85c",
                    "margin-bottom": "0",
                    "box-shadow": "rgb(37, 187, 10) 0px 1px 1px inset, rgb(22, 134, 14) 0px 0px 8px"
                });
                $("#fnerror").removeClass("error-container").addClass("valid-container");

                fname = vall;
            }
        },
        blur : function() {
            $(".f_n").css({
                "box-shadow": "none"
            });
        },
        focus : function() {
            $(this).trigger('keyup');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I add the box-shadow back for a specific error when I focus on it again?

Comment: @maftyycs - I think the best way would be to just trigger the keyup on focus, that way the checks on the value trigger again etc. I've added that to the code above

Answer (score 1):

this can done easily with css, may be this will help u

```css
input[type=text], textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
 
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  
    <div>
        <label for="name">Text Input</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
  
    <div>
        <label for="textarea">Textarea</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with pure CSS:

```css
input {
  margin: 2px 0;
  }

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #666;
  outline: 0;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="email" name="email"><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="password" name="repassword">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this below example code might work, as you haven't added your `HTML and CSS` it difficult to understand what else you have added, but you could add this in your `jquery.`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type='text']").on('focus',function(){
 $(this).css({
   "box-shadow": "inset 0 1px 1px #dab6b6, 0 0 8px #da0707"
   });
 });
  $("input[type='text']").on('blur',function(){
 $(this).css({
   "box-shadow": "inset 0 0px 0px #dab6b6, 0 0 0px #da0707"
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with css only if you whant: (other boxshadow than your example)

```
.f_n:focus {
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 6px 6px 35px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```